# Вертикальная/горизонтальная ориентация компонента Swing

Tags: java, swing

Как повернуть компонент Swing, например ToggleButton на определённое количество градусов.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, вы не можете это сделать средствами Swing. Либо разрабатывайте свой компонент, либо используете более современный JavaFX.